# creating a link to a local file on a locally-run web page (Chrome), while "Local File Links" extenstion is enabled

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I want to use the html  href attribute as a hyperlink to present a local html file, located on my hard rive.I have the following code, and I'm using the Chrome browser:

List: Specified

The "Local File Links" extension is enabled.
I've also tried:
(a) href="file:///F:......\nameOfLocalFile.html">Specified
(b)

List: Specified

It doesn't work and the files are not opened. 
Is there a new way today (11/2019) in html to access other files on my hard drive in Chrome (and in other browsers, possibly). Is there a certain extension in Chrome I am missing or a certain keyword in html for achieving this?

I am running Windows 10 and Using Chrome as default browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have done a simple mistake.
Try to change your \ to /.

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/S1/Desktop/test.html">Click</a>
```

Your problem will be sorted out